# Android，okhttp meanwhile upload file and json

Tags: android, okhttp

I okhttp3, I want to be able to upload files, uploading JSON data, but found only upload HashMap at the same time, I ask, how uploading JSON?I found RequestBody class method create, upload json and upload files method is overloaded

Comment: On their home  page they have an example of sending a json request http://square.github.io/okhttp/

Comment: Oh, I have presented in his GitHub issues, but he told me, please go to stackoverflow to ask authority.

Comment: do you mean multi-part post ?

Comment: thanks,Through your remind me to find, but it is still not very understand, What do you have recommend articles Mody？

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Complex request -----Multipart/form-data

Find some sample code,But I still do not understand:

```
MultipartBody.Builder builder = new MultipartBody.Builder();
        MultipartBody body = builder
                .setType(MultipartBody.FORM)
                .addPart(
                        Headers.of("Content-Disposition", "form-data; name=\"title\""),
                        RequestBody.create(null, "Square Logo"))
                .addPart(
                        Headers.of("Content-Disposition", "form-data; name=\"image\""),
                        RequestBody.create(MEDIA_TYPE_PNG, new File("website/static/logo-square.png")))
                .build();

        Request request = new Request.Builder()
                .header("Authorization", "Client-ID " + IMGUR_CLIENT_ID)
                .url("https://api.imgur.com/3/image")
                .post(body)
                .build();

        Response response = OkHttpUtils.getInstance().getOkHttpClient().newCall(request).execute();
```